# Debugging Errors,Unable To see peoper debugging features enabled

Tags: vscode-debugger

[debugger keys disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u5Z6.png)
here is how it looks. How do i fix it?

i tried debugging and nothing seems to pop up. i was trying to see how the code works (c programming) but the debugger menu is not working also i cant see any variables in debug menu.
[debug menu img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZQwy.png) look at this

it also shows exited with code -1, what does that mean?
it opens a launcch.json file which i have no idea about.